# I need a custom SDL event. Should I modify SDL or get input some other way?

Tags: c++, libraries

I want to modify a linux program written in C++ that uses SDL. I want to add an input source to the program (using an unusual I/O device). The program receives input via SDL. I essentially need to add a new input source, as shown below...

```
    while (SDL_PollEvent (&event)) {
        if (!next) {
            switch (event.type) {
                 case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                        SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
                        //do stuff based on x and y
                        break;

                case SDL_NEW_IO_INPUT_FROM_OBSCURE_DEVICE: 
                        SDL_GetDeviceState(&x, &y);   //this would have to be written into SDL
                        //do stuff based on x and y
                        break;
```

I'm an experienced developer -- but I don't know that much about C++ or SDL.  How hard would it be to modify SDL to take this unusual input? Am I better off using a workaround to get the input? This is for a semester-long project for a masters-level course -- not a long-term software product. So I am looking for the quickest way to get the program taking input -- not the most elegant or maintainable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding events to SDL shouldn't be hard, you just need to make a structure to hold your event data and register with [SDL_RegisterEvents](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RegisterEvents) to get an event id.  From your code you create a new [sdl user event](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UserEvent) set the event id to the one you got from register event and populate the pointers to your real data.  Since the numbers are allocated dynamically they can't be tested for directly in the big switch statement, your users will have to put a default entry in the switch and use if statements to check for your event ID specifically.